# RESTful API User Accounts

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I'm trying to expose RESTful API endpoints for creating user accounts to access my API. So, this would be one of the first things my consumers would use. I'm trying to figure out if this is how I should implement the endpoints, so any feedback / guidance (particularly in complying with REST principles) is highly appreciated.

My current thoughts:

`POST /users` with parameters `name`, `email`, and `password` to register.

`PUT /users/{id}` with parameters `name`, `email`, and/or `password` to update user account.

`DEL /users/{id}` to delete account.

I think the above 3 endpoints handles the create, update, and delete part of the user accounts. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to "log in" (essentially, the user needs to submit `email` and `password` to get an `access_token`) and "log out" (where the `access_token" is nullified).

**LOG IN**

Calls to various other endpoints require Bearer access token. In order to get that access token, I was considering:

`GET /users` with parameters `email` and `password`. The endpoint would return `name`, `email`, `access_token`. **For subsequent calls, I'm unsure if I should change the value of `access_token`.**

`GET /users/{id}` with same parameters as `GET /users`. This means the `{id}` in the path is ignored and useless. **This feels weird.**

**LOG OUT**

`PUT /users/{id}` with parameter `access_token` and the value `null`. Essentially, this would nullify the access token, and any further use of the access token in other endpoints would result in a `401 Unauthorized`.

**UPDATE**

If someone can produce an OpenAPI document showing how this might be implemented, maybe that'll be easier to understand?

Answer (score 6):

It's easier to handle when you have different APIs for different matters.

#### Authentication

`POST /auth` or `POST /login` doesn't matter. Use the one you like most for authentication. As for the response, the token you mentioned is OK.

> GET /users with parameters email and password. The endpoint would return name, email, access_token.

Since we are speaking about REST, we'll assume the API to be [stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130036/how-to-understand-restful-api-is-stateless). So, clients send users' credentials and the server respond with the auth token (`200 OK`) or redirects the client to a new address to follow up with the auth protocol (`302 redirect`).

> **For subsequent calls, I'm unsure if I should change the value of access_token.**

Not necessarily. Tokens can live forever (
although it's not recommended), so that they can be reused over and over. However, the longer they live, the longer is the API exposed to threats, hence vulnerable. The common agreement is then to implement short-living tokens. In 30 seconds or 40 days is up to you, but they should expire eventually. When they expire, clients must ask the server for a new one. A sort of re-login.

Note that, this introduces a new feature: the token life cycle management.

My advice is, don't reinvent the wheel. There's a lot written about the subject. A good site to start with is [OWASP: REST Security](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html)

#### Logout

`POST /logout`. The bearer token is already communicating what system user is involved and what token must be invalidated (expired). This service can be idempotent, doesn't matter if the token was already expired or it doesn't exist, the client only needs to know that it went ok (`200 OK`)

#### Users and accounts

For simplicity, don't mix security management and users management in a single interface.

For example:

- `/users`
- `/accounts`

Each endpoint manages its resource (`User` and `Account` respectively).

There's indeed a 1-to-1 relationship between one `user` and one `account`. We could say that both are the same thing but observed from different standpoints. When we look at the system user from the security standpoint, we "see" `Accounts` (privileges, credentials, tokens, permissions, etc). When we look at the very same system user, from the person who is it, we "see" a human being with personal attributes (name, surname, age, etc). In both cases, both things are essentially the same. A system user.

This said

- `/users` handles the user data and this sort of stuff
- `/accounts` handles the user credentials, grants, roles or/and availability.

The reason for us to do this is segregation of concerns. This way we can attend security without compromising the user' management and vice-versa. It's also easier to reason about each subject when we don't mix them up.

Comment: Is it RESTful to be using verbs as the endpoints?

Comment: RESTfulness has nothing to be with the grammar of the endpoints. The "rule" of not using verbs is addressed to don't transfer any meaning to the URIs others can get attached to. URIs are meaningless. In other words, you don't want others inspecting your URIs in order to know what to do. The action is informed via the HTTP method. However, you will find that these HTTP methods fall short as the API growth in uses cases and once there, simplicity is way more important than any the facto rule we don't fully grasp. Overall if it's, somewhat, preventing us from getting things done.

Comment: I don't have a concept of "users" and "accounts" in my API. Do I really need to separate these two?

Comment: You can mix everything in a single API, but then the "weird" cases like the one detected in your `login` and `logout` will keep appearing. The solution will be segmenting the code with "!if/else" blocks addressed to detect which use cases is handling the endpoint. Or even worse, implementing weird URIs with very little difference among them and doing precisely what you were asking in the first comment.

Comment: `I don't have a concept of "users" and "accounts" ` but still you have the notion "security" and "users". Your API is not reflecting this, but it doesn't mean you don't have both issues. It just happens that for you "users" have a "password" instead of "users" have an "account". You might find this more complicated than just merging everything into user, and it's indeed, but not to the point of making the solution unaffordable.

Comment: Do you have an OpenAPI spec for your proposal? Might be easier for me to understand your idea?

Comment: In my model, if I remove `users`.`name`, do I eliminate the distinct concepts of "users" and "accounts"? I don't actually need any details about the API consumer other than what's required for authentication/authorization (I guess what you call "accounts", but my DB's table name for it is "users").

Comment: Yes, if your concept of `User` only holds the credentials or data required for auth then your right. If at some point, you need to enrich the concept of `User` with personal data (name, surname, age, etc), then you will find that `user` holds too many info and too many responsibilities. When that happens, I split it in two: User and Account. In those cases, what you cal "User" would turn into the half that holds personal data. Its table in DB would be reviewed too. Then we would add a 2nd table "Accounts" and a new entity `Account`, which replaces `User`  in all the security matters.

Comment: When you have both things separated, either in the source code as in the data store, you find that offering two different endpoints `/users` and `/accounts` is a natural choice and makes the management of each entity much simpler.

Comment: When you log in, you effectively create a new session linked to a specific user, identified by a token. `/user` only models static user data, while `/accounts` (or `/auth`, or whatever) models those (active) session tokens. Login and Logout translate to "create session" and "destroy session" respectively, so those actions should fall neatly in your `/accounts` endpoint. This is true even if you don't use actual sessions on the server side, as it's primarily an abstraction.

Comment: I didnt look at it from the life cycle of the data. That's a good point too.

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following:

- Have a dedicated /login endpoint. GET /users is more appropriate for obtaining a list of all registered users of your service; GET /users/{id} is more appropriate for obtaining the (public) profile of that user.
- Use POST to obtain an access token, because the login action should not be idempotent or cacheable (both of which a GET would imply). A user should get a new token for any login action so that they can log-in from multiple devices independently; unless that's explicitly forbidden of course in which case they still would get a new token on every login, the old token would just be invalidated at the same time.
- Similarly: Use POST /logout instead. PUT also implies idempotence, i.e. you should get the same response with the same input when you do it twice. Logout in principle can be idempotent, but only if you can distinguish "this is an old token that once was valid, but is now logged out" from "this is a token that never was valid; someone is trying funny business". The former can get the same successful response every time /logout is accessed, but the latter should always get a 401.

Comment: Is it RESTful to be using verbs as the endpoints?

Comment: Maybe in my context, `GET /users` is to obtain a list of all users the API caller has access to, which will always be one (the caller's user resource). Wouldn't that be a semantic definition of `GET /users`?

Comment: Isn't `POST` to create a new resource? What new resource is being created when the user logs in, or logs out?

Comment: POST can be used for creating new resources, but that's not the only way POST is used in REST APIs. Most of the other verbs ought be to be used in idempotent operations, so POST is often the catch-all verb for every action that's non-idempotent.

Comment: And no, simply using different HTTP verbs on some URL does not make the API RESTful. At least because a single resource isn't nearly enough to represent any even moderately complex API. You'll basically always use multiple different resources in the same API, some of which will use many different verbs, some will use only a few, some may even use a single one.

Comment: Do you have an OpenAPI spec for your proposal? Might be easier for me to understand your idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect relying parties to use a browser based OAuth login procedure, it is not particularly difficult to add user creation to the login workflow: the RP doesn't need to know who it is logging in as until the exchange is complete and it has and it has an access token.  This gives you flexibility for expansion in the future without breaking RPs:

- change what information you collect when users register.
- 2FA support
- CAPTCHAs on account creation/login.

If the RP needs additional information about the user, a simple option is to offer a fixed GET endpoint that will return information about the user identified by the access token used to authenticate the request.  A PUT or PATCH request on the same endpoint could be used to update the user's profile.

If you need a way to logout a the current user, I would again suggest using a fixed endpoint that uses the access token to identify which user to expire the tokens of.  Adding a user ID to the URI just complicates things.